# SSIS 2012 SP1 "Value of null is not valid for stream" error on designer components

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools, ssis-2012, ssdt-bi

I have just migrated a project from SSIS 2005 to SSIS 2012

Apart from the project, I had a custom pipeline component, which was also migrated to .NET 4.0, and installed in SQL Server DTS directory and the GAC, as usual.

After the migration, when I tried to open and configure the migrated component I got the error: "Value of null is not valid for stream".

The error only happened in "SSDT for BI" of VS 2012. When I tried to open and use the component in SQL Server Data Tools (VS 2010, not 2012, shell) it work without flaws.

So, this is a problem exclusive to SQL Server 2012 SP1 and SSDT for BI for VS2012

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the new SSIS Azure Storage components in VS 2012. Followed the same migration steps to .NET 4.0 + installed components in SQL Server DTS directory and the GAC. (Component code downloaded from [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Blob-Storage-fc25adbf#content). When I try to edit the data flow source or destination component in an Integration Services project, I get the VS error: "Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'. Same behavior in VS 2010 with SSDT 2010. I reinstalled VS2012, SSDT2012 and the latest Azure SDK, which did not solve the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem affects SQL Server 2012 SSIS, and, in some occasssions, it doesn't even allow to open SSIS packages.

This error is solved with a Microsoft patch which can be downloaded from this page:

[Micsosoft KB 2832017](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2832017)

Particularly, to solve the problem in VS, as VS is a 32 bit application, you only have to install the x86 download.